# Consulta para retornar valores específicos

Tags: sql, oracle

Na minha tabela `IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA` tenho uma coluna chamada `IDENTIFICADOR`. Esta coluna recebe valores de CPF. Porém existem valores aí que não correspondem a CPF, ou seja , estão fora dos padrões de um CPF (999.999.999-99). Como seria uma `query` que me retornasse os registros que estão fora deste padrão ? E também quero registros que contenham mais e menos de 11 dígitos (valores numéricos).

Comment: Você poderia utilizar expressão regulares nas sua consulta SQL. http://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-em-banco-de-dados-muito-alem-do-like-parte-02/12790

Comment: Você vai ter que criar uma função, para validar se o cpf é valido ou não e depois utilizar essa função na sua consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `REGEXP_LIKE`, conforme segue:

```
SELECT *
FROM IDENTIFICACAO_PESSOA
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(IDENTIFICADOR, '^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}$');
```

Comment: Me retornou o que está no padrão.

Comment: Retorna que não está no padrão: perceba o "NOT".

Comment: Estranho, ao executar aqui retornou o que está no padrão

Comment: Ajustei a resposta, tente novamente! Vai pegar se não for exatamente o padrão agora.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from identificacao_pessoal
where length(identificador) <> 11
```

Dica , repense o modelo.

Comment: No seu caso ele me retorna o que for diferente de 11, e a query pra saber quem está fora do padrão ?

Comment: Sendo que 11 é o padrão do CPF (supondo que zeros a esquerda sejam gravados) , sim.